# best was to get business central customer systemID into dataverse accounts table?

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dataverse

So far i have the standard sync setup between dataverse accounts and business central customers. But I cant edit the fields which are synced.
I require the BC Customer systemID in the dataverse accounts table, but am having absolutely no luck trying to find out how to do it. I am kinda new to BC and Dataverse so not overly skilled in it.

Can someone provide a way to get the systemID into the table?